# How do I substitute a variable for an Array name?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have written JavaScript here to emulate a play in a football game. I created an array of 5 objects where each object is a player. I then proceed to loop through the array and use an if condition to return a number of comparison pts, based on which players are active so that I eventually can compare the opponent's comparison pts to see if the difference warrants a score of a Touchdown, Field Goal, or Pick six.

The second half of the code is to come, but what I want to establish first is the below code being able to work by substituting the team name in all instances with a variable called "whoHasBall."

This way I can use the same loop to point to either the Eagles array or the Giants array, that I will add later.

Below I have pasted the code where I have the Team Name entered as a static name and this code works by returning two active players and returning the total number of comparison pts.

```
/*-----------EaglesVsGiants5.js------------ */

let whoHasBall = "Eagles";

let getRandNum = function (start, range) {
    let getRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
    while (getRand > range) {
        getRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
    };
    return getRand;
}

let Eagles = [{
        name: "Wentz",
        power: 99,
        position: "QB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Jackson",
        power: 85,
        position: "WR",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Shady",
        power: 88,
        position: "RB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Cox",
        power: 99,
        position: "DT",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Jenkins",
        power: 80,
        position: "DB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
];


let TeamComparisonPts = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < Eagles.length; x++) {

    let pow = (Eagles[x].power);

 
    function AdjPlayerPts(rand) {
        return Math.round(pow / (rand * (getRandNum(1, 10))));
    };

    let PlayersPts = (AdjPlayerPts(Eagles[x].random));

   
    if ((Eagles[x].position) === "QB" || (Eagles[x].position) === "WR") {
        console.log("------------------");
        console.log((Eagles[x].name) + " is active on this play and has");
        console.log((PlayersPts) + " pts");
        TeamComparisonPts += PlayersPts;
    };
};

console.log("------------------");
console.log(whoHasBall + " have " + TeamComparisonPts + " Team Comparison Points on this play");
console.log("------------------");
```

So I then decided to take the next step and replace all instances of the Team array name, "Eagles", except of course in the variable declaration and the actual array name that I will reference with the variable "whoHasBall" and the code fell apart. I declared the variable on the Global level for it was my understanding that functions could look out of their local scope. BTW in the first pasted code, the variable "whoHasBall" is only being referenced at the bottom console call to adjust the string

I have pasted that code here:

```
let whoHasBall = "Eagles";

let getRandNum = function (start, range) {
    let getRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
    while (getRand > range) {
        getRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
    };
    return getRand;
}

let Eagles = [{
        name: "Wentz",
        power: 99,
        position: "QB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Jackson",
        power: 85,
        position: "WR",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Shady",
        power: 88,
        position: "RB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Cox",
        power: 99,
        position: "DT",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Jenkins",
        power: 80,
        position: "DB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
];


let TeamComparisonPts = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < whoHasBall.length; x++) {

    let pow = (whoHasBall[x].power);

 
    function AdjPlayerPts(rand) {
        return Math.round(pow / (rand * (getRandNum(1, 10))));
    };

    let PlayersPts = (AdjPlayerPts(whoHasBall[x].random));

   
    if ((whoHasBall[x].position) === "QB" || (whoHasBall[x].position) === "WR") {
        console.log("------------------");
        console.log((whoHasBall[x].name) + " is active on this play and has");
        console.log((PlayersPts) + " pts");
        TeamComparisonPts += PlayersPts;
    };
};

console.log("------------------");
console.log(whoHasBall + " have " + TeamComparisonPts + " Team Comparison Points on this play");
console.log("------------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this works for u!!!

```js
let getRandNum = function(start, range) {
  let getRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
  while (getRand > range) {
    getRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
  };
  return getRand;
}

let whoHasBall = {
  Eagles: [{
      name: "Wentz",
      power: 99,
      position: "QB",
      random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
      name: "Jackson",
      power: 85,
      position: "WR",
      random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
      name: "Shady",
      power: 88,
      position: "RB",
      random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
      name: "Cox",
      power: 99,
      position: "DT",
      random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
      name: "Jenkins",
      power: 80,
      position: "DB",
      random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
  ]
};





let TeamComparisonPts = 0;


Object.keys(whoHasBall).map(team => {

  whoHasBall[team].map(player => {


    let pow = (player.power);

    function AdjPlayerPts(rand) {
      return Math.round(pow / (rand * (getRandNum(1, 10))));
    };

    let PlayersPts = (AdjPlayerPts(player.random));


    if ((player.position) === "QB" || (player.position) === "WR") {
      console.log("------------------");
      console.log((player.name) + " is active on this play and has");
      console.log((PlayersPts) + " pts");
      TeamComparisonPts += PlayersPts;
    }
  })
  console.log("------------------");
  console.log(team + " have " + TeamComparisonPts + " Team Comparison Points on this play");
  console.log("------------------");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have realized what I was doing wrong here and fixed my code. I have pasted it below but here is basically what I needed to do.

On the first line of code:

```
let whoHasBall = "Eagles";
```

I had to:

1. remove the quotes. In reading further I found that this is simply passing a reference to the original array Eagles to a new variable called whoHasBall, which then really becomes the same array.
2. I had to move the line of code below the Eagles array so the Eagles array is initialized first.

This solved this particular problem.

Full corrected code is here:

```
let getRandNum = function (start, range) {
    let getRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
    while (getRand > range) {
        getRand = Math.floor((Math.random() * range) + start);
    };
    return getRand;
}

let Eagles = [{
        name: "Wentz",
        power: 99,
        position: "QB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Jackson",
        power: 85,
        position: "WR",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Shady",
        power: 88,
        position: "RB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Cox",
        power: 99,
        position: "DT",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
    {
        name: "Jenkins",
        power: 80,
        position: "DB",
        random: getRandNum(1, 10)
    },
];

let whoHasBall = Eagles;

let TeamComparisonPts = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < whoHasBall.length; x++) {

    let pow = (whoHasBall[x].power);

 
    function AdjPlayerPts(rand) {
        return Math.round(pow / (rand * (getRandNum(1, 10))));
    };

    let PlayersPts = (AdjPlayerPts(whoHasBall[x].random));

   
    if ((whoHasBall[x].position) === "QB" || (whoHasBall[x].position) === "WR") {
        console.log("------------------");
        console.log((whoHasBall[x].name) + " is active on this play and has");
        console.log((PlayersPts) + " pts");
        TeamComparisonPts += PlayersPts;
    };
};

console.log("------------------");
console.log(whoHasBall + " have " + TeamComparisonPts + " Team Comparison Points on this play");
console.log("------------------");
```